# How can I use Bowser's Fire Breath to Edge-Guard?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

So it seems to me that [Bowser's](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Bowser#In_Super_Smash_Bros._Melee) [Fire Breath](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Fire_Breath) (neutral special) could potentially be used as an edge guarding move, given that it is angled downwards, and can damage characters trying to recover. Currently when using it to edge guard I will stand on the edge, and use the move to hit players trying to recover by ensuring the flames are sprayed downwards off of the ledge (as opposed to horizontally off of the edge).

This tends to work against characters with poor recoveries that are easily cancelled (like Yoshi, whose jump is easily stolen, or Ness, whose recovery can be easily neutralized using the fire), but I am having problems using the move to guard against more diverse recoveries, like Pikachu (who can usually recover by avoiding me and my fire entirely), or Fox/Falco (who can use their recovery to push straight through the fire, often damaging me).

So how can I use the Fire Breath to edge guard? Is there a general strategy that differs from the one I described above? Are there specific strategies used against specific characters?

Comment: I only play casually, so I'm not able to answer this question with any great amount of detail, but I would assume that if a character had an ability that could perfectly edge guard against everyone else, that character would be the only one being played. The fact that some characters can get past it more easily than others is by design.

Comment: @MageXy Yes of course. I'm just looking to see if there are existing strategies that work better than mine, so as to maximize my use of the move in edge guarding situations